# Show sets are not homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Consider the following sets: 
$$A = \big \{ (x, 0) : -1 \leq x \leq 1 \big \} \cup \big \{ (0,y): 0 \leq y \leq 1 \big \}$$
$$B = \big \{(x, y) : x^2 + y^2 = 1 \} \cup \big \{ (x, 0) : 1 \leq x \leq 2 \big \}$$
$C = [0, 1]$ (line segment), $D = \mathbb{S}^1$ (circle). Show that these sets are not homeomorphic to each other.

I have already shown that $C$ and $D$ are not homeomorphic. I am stuck on showing that $A$ is not homeomorphic to $B$ and that $B$ is not homeomorphic to $C.$

I am trying to apply a proposition to prove these spaces are not homeomorphic:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces. Suppose there is $x \in X$ such that $X\setminus\{x\}$ has $m$ connected components. If there is no $y \in Y$ such that $Y\setminus\{y\}$ has $m$ connected components, then $X$ and $Y$ are not homeomorphic.

but I am having so much trouble. Any help gladly accepted!

Comment: Look at the origin in $A$ and $(1,0)$ in $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $A$ looks like $\perp$, and $B$ is a circle with an outward antenna.

To show that $A$ is not like the others, take out the origin in $A$, and consider where the corresponding point could be in another space assuming that $A$ is homeomorphic to it.

To show that $B$ is not like the others, note that when you take out $(1,0)$ from $B$ you obtain two connected components, while taking out any other point results in a connected space. Assuming you can find homeomorphisms to $C$, consider what the corresponding points of the endpoints of the interval are. Or alternatively consider the corresponding points of an interior point of the unit interval would be under a homeomorphism.